# Rule of calculation of residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $U \subset \Bbb C$ be open and $f,g:U \to \Bbb C$ be holomorphic. I wanna show that if $g$ has a simple zero in $z_0\in U$, then
$$\operatorname{Res}\biggl(\frac{f}{g},z_0\biggr)=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$
The proof I use is: Because $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic we can expand them as entire serie
$$f(z)=b_0+b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)+ \dots$$
and
$$g(z)=c_1(z-z_0)+c_2(z-z_0)+ \dots$$
Where we already used that $g$ has a simple zero in $z_0$.
$$\frac{b_0+b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+ \dots}{c_1(z-z_0)+c_2(z-z_0)^2+ \dots}=\frac{1}{z-z_0}(\frac{b_0+b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-a)^2+ \dots}{c_1+c_2(z-z_0)+\dots})$$
The right fraction is nothing else than the holomorphic function $h(z):=\frac{(z-z_0)f(z)}{g(z)}$ with $h(z_0)=\frac{b_0}{c_1}=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$. But this should be the end of the proof. But why? I don't understand the end...

EDIT: Is it not wrong? Should it not be that $f$ can be represented as a Laurent serie near $z_0$ and not as an entire function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient$$\frac{b_0+b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{c_1+c_2(z-z_0)+c_3(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}$$is the quotient of two holomorphic functions and therefore it is holomorphic; besides, it maps $z_0$ into $\frac{b_0}{c_1}$. It can be written, near $z_0$, as $d_0+d_1(z-z_0)+d_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots$, with $d_0=\frac{b_0}{c_1}$. So, near $z_0$,$$\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{d_0}{z-z_0}+d_1+d_2(z-z_0)+\cdots$$Therefore, by the definition of residue,$$\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac fg,z_0\right)=d_0=\frac{b_0}{c_1}.$$

Comment: Don't we have that for the Laurent expansion $c_{-1}$ is residue of $f$ in $z_0$?

Comment: What is $c_{-1}$?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I mean if f has a Laurent expansion, then the residue is the coefficient with indices $-1$, not? No, now I see... There is a shift.. $d_0$ is indeed the coefficient with indice $-1$. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Yes. If$$\varphi(z)=\cdots+c_{-2}(z-z_0)^{-2}+c_{-1}(z-z_0)^{-1}+c_0+c_1(z-z_0)+c_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots$$then $\operatorname{res}(\varphi,z_0)=c_{-1}$.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: I don't understand those questions at the end. Nobody claims that $g$ is an entire function. On the other hand, since it is analytic, since $g(z_0)=0$, and since $g'(z_0)\ne0$, its Taylor series is of the form$$c_1(z-z_0)+c_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots$$with $c_1\ne0$.

Comment: Oh sorry I got confused! I mean $f$, of course we have that $g$ has a simple zero in $z_0$ and hence all coefficients smaller equal $c_0$ are zero of the laurent serie but for $f$ we know nothing

Comment: But $f$ is holomorphic and $z_0$ belongs to its domain. So, it has a *Taylor* series centered at $z_0$. And, again, nobody is claiming that it is an entire function.

Answer (score 0):

An idea for you: since $\;z_0\;$ is *a simple zero* of $\;g(z)\;$ , we have that $\;g(z)=(z-z_0)h(z)\;$ , where $\;h\;$ is analytic and non-zero in some neighborhood of $\;z_0\;$ ,
and $\;f(z)\neq0\;$ in the same neighborhood. Observe also that $\;g'(z)=h(z)+(z-z_0)h'(z)\implies g'(z_0)=h(z_0)\;$

$$\text{Res}_{z_0}\,\left(\frac fg\right)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)}{h(z)}=\frac{f(z_0)}{h(z_0)}=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$